# Complete contribution to git repo

Tags: github, repository, fork, open-source, sourcetree

I want to contribute to a git repository. From the tutorials and other things what i found is i have to fork the repository to achieve this. So i forked the repository and then i cloned my copy of code in SourceTree.

Now in the repository property i changed the user name to the owner of that repository in the optional extended integration section.

Then i changed the code where needed and pushed to master branch. Currently its showing that i made contribution in my repository but i want those changes to reflect in the main repo.

Can anyone guide me how can i do this.

Comment: You need to issue a pull request then.

Comment: ok, i just tried and the steps were easy. Thank you. Now if the owner wants then he can merge my changes into the master. I was thinking it was used to pull the repository. Thank you again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to issue a [pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/about-pull-requests/) then.

As long as the core developer (team) has not added you as a contributor and granted writing rights on the repository, there's no way you can contribute directly. Your only option then is to work on your own fork and hope the developers have and take the time to review and incorporate your pull requests.